# Fitting models to 2d data

Tags: tensorflow

I am reading the documentation on tf.lattice (https://www.tensorflow.org/lattice/overview)

[image]

I am wondering how the training data was created/trained. Is it represented by (x,y) intpositions and some intensity value output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the answer already there?

[image]

"
The function  can capture non-linear interactions between features. You can think of the lattice parameters as the height of poles set in the ground on a regular grid, and the resulting function is like cloth pulled tight against the four poles.

With  features and 2 vertices along each dimension, a regular lattice will have  parameters. To fit a more flexible function, you can specify a finer-grained lattice over the feature space with more vertices along each dimension. Lattice regression functions are continuous and piecewise infinitely differentiable.

"
EDIT-

Specifically for these pictures, they have given the example of dateset ranking restaurants(links are below). These graphs shows number of reviews(Y-Axis)/Average rating (x-axis).It has source code also. 
https://www.tensorflow.org/lattice/tutorials/shape_constraints
https://www.tensorflow.org/lattice
[image]

[image]

Comment: No I don't see the answer here, this does not explain how other models are fit to the same data or what the dataset is.

Comment: umm...they have given this example here,-https://www.tensorflow.org/lattice/tutorials/keras_layers. are you looking for dataset and model "specifically" which generated these model in given pictures? or in general how Lattice uses data? may be I should have asked it earlier.

Comment: I think the latter is answered in the post you answered but the former is not, I am curious how the other models were generated with the same data that the lattice model was generated.

Comment: Here you go.. its  a dataset for ranking restaurants. https://www.tensorflow.org/lattice/tutorials/shape_constraints

Comment: thank you that's what I am looking for.